# Can a C++ template determine if the instance being declared/defined is constant?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

For a given template, for example `std::string`, can the template detect if the instance of `string` being declared/defined is a constant. (Note: I am not asking about template arguments.)

```
std::string mutable_string("a string that may possibly be changed");
```

versus

```
const std::string immutable_string("a string that will not change);
```

If this is possible, the template could allocate exactly the amount of heap storage for the string literal supplied to the constructor. Furthermore, non-const, non-ctor/dtor methods' code generation could be elided (unless some translation unit defines a non-const string).

I was hoping for something semantically similar to:

```
is_constant<std::string>(*this)::value
```

Is it possible to compare the type of the instance to that type with the const qualifier stripped?

**Update/Clarification**: Extending the `std::string` example, could a template specialization for `const std::string` be able to declare inspectors as `constexpr` (e.g. `size()`, `capacity()`?

Comment: *"For a given template, for example std::string"* **`std::string` is not a template. `std::basic_string` is.**

Comment: @Manu343726: I imagine he refers to `std::basic_string`... at any rate, an object can *never* be of a template type, but of an instantiation of a template, and that is no longer a template. That is if you really want to go into pedantry.

Comment: You could use a function to create mutable/immutable strings: `auto mutable_string = make_mutable_string(".."); auto immutable_string = make_immutable_string("..");`

Answer (score 5):

If I get you right:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_constant(T&) {
    return false;
}

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_constant(const T&) {
    return true;
}

template <bool Value>
void print() {
    std::cout << (Value ? "true " : "false ");
}

struct X {
    void a() { print<is_constant(*this)>(); }
    void b() const { print<is_constant(*this)>(); }
};

int main() {
    X x;
    // false
    x.a();
    // true
    x.b();
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

However, if you want to detect if an object will be const qualified, it is impossible - a constructor is never const.

Comment: was going to post something similar +1

Comment: I think the question is more as of whether the constructor can know whether the instance being constructed is const or not. The code above won't be able to detect this, as in the example with `X` the const-ness is inferred from the implicit `this` argument (`const` at the far right of the function declaration), but that cannot be `const` in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot detect whether the object being constructed will be marked `const` or not. If your concern is to provide exact memory allocation, just do, it will be fine. If the string is not const then it will grow as needed when needed.

Regarding the code generation, members of templates are usually generated on demand, so if they are not used, they won't be generated, so there is no win there. The *usually* is because this is not the case in explicit instantiations, and in this particular case your implementation might be doing an explicit instantiation for performance reasons (compiler time), since for the common instantiations of `basic_string` (`char`, `wchar_t`) the vendor can provide the implementation already in binary form in a linked library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not the answer I'd hoped for, but thank you just the same.  What prompted me to inquire was that my compiler uses an algorithm to increase the buffer size by 50% and copy the old contents to the new buffer. This is done iteratively as the ctor pushes back the literal supplied.  This means that strings are over allocated by ~25% on average. Providing my own allocator won't help here..  I agree on your point of eliding non-const methods being a non-win.

Comment: @evangineer: You should raise an issue with your vendor if any of the constructors taking the value over-allocate, and worse if they cause multiple allocations to occur! Out of curiosity, what is the compiler/version?

Comment: @evangineer How about constructing from a pair of iterators instead of a `const char*`? `static const char* const foo_ = "a string that will not change"; std::string foo{foo_, foo_ + strlen(foo_)}` is likely to result in a `string` with `foo.capacity() == foo.size()`. Even given a slightly brain-damaged implementation.

Comment: @casey: tried that (and many others). `static const char* const foo_ = "1234567890123456"; std::string foo(foo_, foo_+strlen(foo_));`
allocates 32 bytes on the heap and `size() == 16` and `capacity() == 31`.

Comment: @evangineer IIRC, the Visual C++ `string` always allocates capacities that are one less ('\0' terminator space) than a multiple of 16, since it "knows" that the standard allocator allocates memory in 16-byte blocks. The excess capacity would simply be lost to fragmentation otherwise.